# Opportunities to Play Online Chess with Grandmasters for a 2000 Elo Player

Tags: tournament, online-chess, elo, grandmaster

I'm an avid chess player with an Elo rating of around 2000, and I'm interested in exploring opportunities to play online chess against Grandmasters.

Are there any online platforms or tournaments where players of my level can compete against or play with Grandmasters? I'm curious about both casual and competitive environments.

Additionally, if such opportunities exist, how does one qualify or register for these events?

Comment: One option is to hire a GM trainer.  Some chess content creators play their followers sometimes so you could look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ways where you can get a match vs GMs. I've played a bunch of them in the following ways:

1. Many GMs like Minh Le, Benjamin Bok, Eric Hansen, and Hikaru stream on [Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/directory/category/chess-1). Sometimes, they play against their viewers through arenas and individual challenges. So, if you tune in to those streams, I'm pretty sure you'll be able to get a game versus them.
2. Apart from streaming, there are online arenas regularly on [chess.com](https://www.chess.com) and [lichess.org](https://www.lichess.org)(for example, Titled Tuesday, Titled Arena, and Bullet Brawl) where several titled players participate(including many GMs). If you have a title, you'll be able to verse them. If you don't have one, don't worry; there are other arenas where GMs participate(Warmup for Titled Arenas, Community Events, etc.).
3. There are GM trainers available for coaching on [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/coach) and [lichess.org](https://www.lichess.org/coach). You can contact them for personalised training games, too. In return, they'll charge you some money.

Good luck!